# How to pass username and password to a web service from within an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, macos

Have a look to this code snippet:-

`CommonService objcommonService;

 NetworkCredential myCredentials = new NetworkCredential("144552", "F@mous123456");

 objcommonService.Credentials = myCredentials;`

This is a C#.net code. In this snippet  "`objcommonService`" is a object of the webservice "`CommonService`". This webservice pre authenticates the user against its supplied credentials.In C#.NET `NetworkCredential` is a standard class of the .NET .

**If I am trying to hit a webservice which requires these credentials in my iPhone app , How should I pass?**

Is there any way to do it so that the user of my app will not face any difficulty like "Authentication Failed !!" when he/she uses my app.
The webservice pre authenticates the user.And I need to pass my credentials as my app calls for the service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implement the auth stuff by using the following delegate method in URLConnection

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSURLCredential *newCredential;
    newCredential=[NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username
                                             password:password
                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential
           forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

} else {

    [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    // inform the user that the user name and password
    // in the preferences are incorrect
}
```

}

Hope this helps